Difference between bind and on_press method in kivy?
I'm newbie.
Could anyone explain the difference between the bind method and the on_press method with Button in Kivy?
If I want to change the text of a Label why I should use the bind method, as  suggest in many tutorials, instead of
use simply the on_press method directly in the construct of Button?
Thank you
It's a theoretic question, no code tested.

Do people say not to? Would be willing to read those 'tutorials', some example urls to those would be helpful. I'm nowhere near expert on kivy to say this but I also just override on_press on ButtonBehavior derivatives.

Well, first of all, you don't have to do it through bind at all.
Secondly, you asked to explain the difference between them, so the water method on_press works when the button is pressed, and the bind method, so to speak, catches certain events that you enumerate to it, and when those events are triggered, it calls the function you specify, note If you handle an event, then that event must be present in the events that bind handles on a particular object.
For example
btn=Button()
btn.bind(on_press=lambda _:None)

Here we have created a button, and if it is clicked, the on_press method will be triggered, since our handler handles it at our button, it will call lambda function.
I hope I was able to explain to you a little bit how it works, and I also hope that the translator translated everything correctly.
